# user Log In, let the users in without errors (SWIFT) (Parse)

Tags: swift, registration

i'm making an app that required Logging In. the problem is when i run my app to try it and type wrong user info it proceed to the next view controller without giving the error !. Heres my code i don't whats the problem !

{

```
@IBOutlet weak var ActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var Message: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ActivityIndicator.hidden = true
    ActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func LogInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    LogIn()

}

func LogIn() {

    // Start activity indicator
    ActivityIndicator.hidden = false
    ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    // if there is a user
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = UsernameTextField.text
    user.password = PasswordTextField.text


    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(UsernameTextField.text, password:PasswordTextField.text) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



        if user != nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LogInToHomeVC", sender: self)}

            println("Logged In")


        } else {

            self.ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            if let Message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                self.Message.text = "\(Message)"}

            println("Could Not Find User")

        }
    }




}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

so the question is how to let the user try again and not let him enter the Home Page?

Comment: Please, provide the error

Comment: @ULazdins when i run my app and type user info it give error and don't proceed to the next view controller. i need a code for user registration and error messages like (invalid email, username taken .etc)

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: @ULazdins please, go back to the above code and see if my code is wrong please

Comment: The code looks OK to me.

Comment: @ULazdins see my logging page, the error is when i type wrong info and then tap the Login button it proceed to the next view controller and i don't want  that to happen i want to show a message that the user has typed a wrong info.